# Alpinejs Laravel displaying text from function onscreen

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I am new to Alpine JS. Currently, I made radio buttons that when altered show a single entry from the database. How can one run a function on each radio button click instead of just x-text?

Here is my code:

Radio button

```
<template x-model="Date" :key="Date.id" x-for="Date in Dates">
     <tr>
        <td><input x-model="Three" name="CheckThing1" type="radio" :value='Date.Location_Name' /></td>                                
        <td><span :value="Date.id" x-text="Date.Date"></span></td>
     </tr>

<!-- WHERE I WOULD LIKE A NEW TABLE QUERY TO BE SHOWN ON CHANGE OF RADIO BUTTON -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Data1</th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <!-- I can console out a simple Hello world function, but cannot display the result on screen, only in console. -->
            <td><span x-init="$watch('Three', value => console.log(Test123()))" x-text="Three"></span></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Add a work code playground link would provide much help here instead of just code.

Comment: Please explain better your problem

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you click on a radio button?